# Salesforce Lightning - wheelnav.js question

Tags: javascript, lightning-apps

I'm trying to use the wheelnav.js library to create a wheel navigation in my lightning component. For some reason when the wheel renders, the wheel will not render correctly.. The size the wheel renders, is dependent on my browser window size.. If I make my browser window size larger the wheel renders incorrectly, but if I make my browser size extremely small the wheel renders correctly. I'm not quiet sure how to approach this, since lightning so so new. Any suggestions on why the wheel is not rendering correctly? Possibly SVG related?

Wheelnav.js site:

http://wheelnavjs.softwaretailoring.net/

Current way wheel is rendering in app:

[image: Current way wheel renders]

Right now my code for my component is pretty basic:

Component:

```
<aura:component >
<ltng:require scripts='/resource/WheelNav, /resource/raphael' afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.doInit}"/>


<div id="wheelDiv">

</div>
```

Controller:

```
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper){
            helper.createWheel();
    },
})
```

Helper:

```
({
    createWheel : function() {
        var wheel = new wheelnav("wheelDiv");
        wheel.initWheel(["init", "create", "navigate", "refresh"]);
        wheel.createWheel();
    }
})
```

Comment: I've used wheelnavjs a fair bit. Do you mind sharing the code snippet for your lightning component?

Comment: Sure. I've added it to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Set the height and width on the `wheelDiv`. For example in your CSS:

```
#wheelDiv {
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
}
```